# Making the Mandelbrot Fractal in Desmos Online Graphing Calculator

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, fractals

I would like to make the following "animation" of the Mandelbrot Set using the Online Desmos Graphing Calculator app - as seen over here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naqgsOOEHJs

[image]

I couldn't clearly see the equations being used in this video, so I followed the instructions from link provided in the references ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P23UI9cPCQk&t=0s). I manually entered the 8 equations from the video into the Desmos Graphing Calculator:

[image]

However, not only does the graph (set of equations) I have made not look like the first graph - when I zoom into the graph I made, I don't see any repeating fractal patterns.

- Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?
- What can I do to fix this, so that I also get a fractal pattern I can see through zooming?
- If possible, could someone try to make a Mandelbrot Set on Desmos that shows "zoom fractals" and post the link to the graph on Desmos?

Thank you!

Comment: And did you try to make more iterations to see what happens?

Comment: You need more iterations and a $<$ not an $=$ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hvrhuvaue5

Comment: David P : This is exactly what I was looking for! Just a question : Can you please explain the "commas and periods" used in these functions? Thanks!

Comment: David P: I posted a follow-up question over here based on the excellent work you have done https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402462/meaning-of-commas-and-periods-in-mathematical-functions - could you please check it out if you have time? Thank you!

Comment: José C Ferreira : It would appear as though more iterations was the answer!

Comment: @antonoyaro8: To get someone's attention, put "@" in front of their name (as I did with your name in this comment). Note that this only works for the poster of a question/answer, and for people who have commented. "@name"-ing a random person does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I use to play with the iterated sequence
$$z_0=0+i0, \quad c=c_1+ic_2,\qquad \quad z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c,$$ and drawing the approximation to the [Mandelbrot set](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunto_de_Mandelbrot), in which $|z_n|\leq r$, to some $r>0$. [Here](https://realpython.com/mandelbrot-set-python/) you find how to draw some things with Phyton.

If you write $z=x+iy$, you can see that $$z_n^2+c=(x_n^2-y_n^2+c_1)+i(2x_ny_n+c_2).$$

This gives you a glimpse to define the function
$$f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$$ and play with things like
$$f(f(x,y))+(x,y)=(f_1(x,y)^2-f_2(x,y)^2+x,2f_1(x,y)f_2(x,y)+y),$$ that can be written as $$g_{n+1}(x,y)=f(g_{n}(x,y))+(x,y),$$ with  $$g_1(x,y)=f(x,y).$$ Then you can draw the implicitly curve $|g_n(x,y)|=r$ as you can see [here in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bkhv7u4hif?lang=pt-BR).

With the implicit given curves in mind you can use your preferred programing language to draw the curves and animate it.

You can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=291cP_51htA) the second part of the video you mention in your question.

An interesting discussion on how to parametrize the boundary of the Mandelbrot set that I found on SearchOnMath is this [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48642/parametrization-of-the-boundary-of-the-mandelbrot-set).