# Meaning of "Commas and Periods" in Mathematical Functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, notation, graphing-functions, computer-algebra-systems

Can someone please help me understand the meaning of "commas and periods" that appear on the right side of mathematical functions?

For example, in another question ([Making the Mandelbrot Fractal in Desmos Online Graphing Calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401337/making-the-mandelbrot-fractal-in-desmos-online-graphing-calculator)), I learned how to make the "Mandelbrot Fractal" using an online graphing calculator: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hvrhuvaue5

[image]

I noticed that in some of these mathematical equations, there are "periods and commas" that appear on the right hand side of these equations:

[image]

Normally, I would have thought that:

- "Commas" generally appear on the left hand side of mathematical equations to indicate which variables are included in the function. For example, a function F(x,y,z) = z*y - x : commas are used to indicate that the function "F" is made up of variables "x", "y" and "z". For instance, what does "x,2z" mean in the function f(z)?
- On the other hand, I have usually seen "periods" as another notation for indicating "multiplication" (apart from indicating "decimals", which is clearly not the case here) - but for some reason, I do not think that the "period" is referring to multiplication here. I was thinking that maybe the "period" might indicate a "nested function" , but I also do not think that this is the case here. For instance, what does "z.y^2" mean in the function D(z)?

Can someone please help me understand the meaning of "periods and commas" in mathematical functions?

Thank you!

Comment: @littleO: it looks to me as if $z.x$ and $z.y$ denote the $x-$ and $y-$components of the vector $z$.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a question which is less about mathematical notation, and more about how Desmos.  As such, I don't think that it is really on-topic here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are two very different questions.

## Dot notation

This is actually **not** standard mathematics notation, but special notation used in Desmos that other software/textbooks/mathematicians would not necessarily understand. In Desmos, if `p` is a point $(a,b)$, then `p.x` denotes its $x$-coordinate $a$. Similarly, `p.y` denotes its $y$-coordinate. This works whether or not the coordinates are named `x` and `y`, or whether or not they're abstract: `(3,4).y` works fine and is $4$. But this is just Desmos notation.

*Sometimes*, in mathematics we might write $p_x$ to denote the $x$-coordinate of the point $p$, but the subscript $x$ could mean something else/be ambiguous, so it's best to explain your notation.

## Commas

Commas have many different meanings in mathematics. The relevant one in the definition of $f(z)$ in your image is to separate two coordinates of a point. $f(z)$ takes in a point $z=(z_x,z_y)$ (with coordinates that one would write in Desmos as `z.x` and `z.y` instead of subscripts), and outputs another point with first coordinate $z_x^2-z_y^2+x$ and second coordinate $2z_xz_y+y$ (here $+x$ and $+y$ are other parameters not necessarily related to $z$, which is a little confusing), so we write the coordinates of the output point together with a comma as $(z_x^2-z_y^2+x,2z_xz_y+y)$. A much simpler usage would be the point $(3,4)$ with $x$-coordinate $3$ and $y$-coordinate $4$. If you are not familiar with $x$ and $y$-coordinates of points in the plane, you may need to study the [cartesian/coordinate plane](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:foundation-algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:algebra-overview-history/v/descartes-and-cartesian-coordinates).

Comment: So $z.x^2$ means $(z.x)^2$?

Comment: @Acccumulation yes